# Classic ASP: inserting into an array and getting type mismatch

Tags: arrays, asp-classic, type-mismatch

I am trying to insert an int into one array and a string into another. For some reason I can't insert the int or string no matter how I try. Here is the code

```
dim siteList,siteNameList, strQuery
Set oConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
set oRs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
oConn.Open strConnQuery
strQuery = "Select zSiteID as id, zSiteNm as Name from vSite"
set ors = oConn.Execute(strQuery)
z=0
Do While Not oRs.EOF
   sID=oRs("id")
   sName=oRs("Name")
   if InStr(oRs("Name"),"'")>0 then
       sOut = replace(strorigFileName,"'"  ,"")
       siteList(z)=sID
       siteNameList(z)=sOut
   else
       siteList(z)=sID(this is where the error occurs first)
       siteNameList(z)=sName

   end if
   z=z+1
   oRs.MoveNext
Loop
oConn.Close
```

I have tried converting it to different things but that hasn't helped at all. I have no idea what is wrong so any information would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: And what is that error?  Type mismatch?

Comment: yea no matter what I convert it to thats what I get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In classic ASP you need to declare a size for arrays:

```
dim siteList(5)
```

Comment: Really? Before I had this code and it worked fine dim siteList, strQuery
    Set oConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
    set oRs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    oConn.Open strConnQuery
    strQuery = "Select zSiteID, zSiteNm from vSite"
    set ors = oConn.Execute(strQuery)
    siteList=oRs.getRows()

Comment: YEAH that was it!!!! So why can I sometimes not assign a length and other times I have to. Is it because my array ended up being around 280 elements?

Comment: Getrows looks at the size of the recordset and sets its size automagically.

Comment: @Tim: Why aren't you still using `GetRows`? Seems to me that would be a better solution.  Just post process the retrieved array to update any name containing a '.

Comment: So are you suggesting the GetRows, populate the array then cycle through array and replace the '? If so why do you think it would be a better solution. I am newish to asp and would love to know the optimal way to do things.

Comment: getrows is really fast, so yes. do it that way.

Comment: @Tim VBScript can automagically assign runtime value only for the basic types line number, string or Date/Time - when it comes to arrays it won't assign the type by itself because when it see `siteList(z)` it looks for function called `siteList` that should get `z` as its argument. To tell the engine `siteList` is array you have to do what this answer says. In case function returns an array that array has to be declared properly in the function - so somewhere inside GetRows array is being declared. :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648569/type-mismatch-on-an-array-assignment-in-asp) to a similar question that describes why that's happening.

You want to check the number of records in the return set(ors) and either ReDim the array or initialize it after you know the size needed.